Spring Data specifications with correlated subquery
How one using spring data specifications can do the equivalent of this:
select a.*, (select count(1) from b where b.a_id = a.id) as count
from a;
If this is not possible is there an equivalent?

You can add an additional field count to your entity A, the value of which will be calculated by the correlated subquery:
@Entity
class A {
    
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @Formula("(select count(1) from b where b.a_id = id)")
  private Long count;
}

Then, having created a repository for entity A:
public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<A, Long> {
}

You can get the required result using findAll() method.

Thank you so much for your answer! This is indeed what I did while I was waiting for an answer. I'm thrilled this is an accepted solution, as I was not sure about this. Do you see any downside to this?

@minihulk22 Correlated subqueries in most cases will degrade the performance of your application. You should use a separate query to count the number of entities SELECT a_id, COUNT(1) FROM b WHERE a_id IN :ids GROUP BY a_id.
